# Metal fragment shader bound resource acting erratically on macOS

Tags: macos, fragment-shader, metal

This problem has been stumping me, and I can't figure it out.  I've got a few different shaders which use the same resource, a structure with a bunch of lighting values.  The first shader to use it works fine -- the second one does not.  Seems like it might be getting zeroes.  The third shader to use it also works fine.

If I don't have any objects which use the first shader, then the second one works.  And the third one does NOT work.  The resource never changes, it's an MTLBuffer I set once.  And, if I GPU Frame Capture, the values reported in the draw calls are all correct, all the time.  Yet nothing shows up for the shaders that don't work.

The reason I think it is this one particular struct that is fluctuating is that if I hard-code the values into the shader instead of reading the struct values, then that also works.  It's driving me crazy.

I am not sure what kind of code examples will serve here.  Here is the structure and how I am using it.  I'm not binding any other resources to this particular index, anywhere else in the program.

```
struct Light {
    packed_float3 color;      // 0 - 2
    float ambientIntensity;          // 3
    packed_float3 direction;  // 4 - 6
    float diffuseIntensity;   // 7
    float shininess;          // 8
    float specularIntensity;  // 9
    float dummy1,dummy2;
    /*
     _______________________
     |0 1 2 3|4 5 6 7|8 9    |
     -----------------------
     |       |       |       |
     | chunk0| chunk1| chunk2|
     */
}__attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
```

... shader code ....

```
float4 ambientColor = float4(1,1,1,1)  * color * 0.25;
//Diffuse
float diffuseFactor = max(0.0,dot(interpolated.normal, float3(0.0,0.5,-1.0))); // 1
float4 diffuseColor = float4(light.color,1) * color  * 0.5 * diffuseFactor ; // 2
//Specular
float3 eye = normalize(interpolated.fragmentPosition); //1
float3 reflection = reflect(float3(0.0,0.5,-1.0),interpolated.normal); // 2
float specularFactor = pow(max(0.0, dot(reflection, eye)), 10.0); //3
float4 specularColor = float4(float3(1,1,1)* 2 * specularFactor ,color.w);//4
color = (ambientColor + diffuseColor + specularColor);
color = clamp(color, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Anyone have any ideas about what could be the trouble?  Also, this is only happening on the Mac.  On iOS it works fine.

EDIT: It seems like when the shader is failing, it is simply unable to access the resource at all.  For example, I tried just setting my fragment return color to equal the light color, with no modifications.

And it produces nothing -- not even black!  If I replace that statement with one of these two, I get white and black:

```
color = float4(1,1,1, 1);  // produces white
color = float4(0,0,0, 1);  //produces black

color = float4(light.color.xyz, 1);  // nothing at all
```

It is like the fragment shader is just aborting when it is trying to access the light structure -- otherwise I would get SOMETHING in my color, with a forced alpha value of 1.  I don't get it.